# Where to register ActivatedRoute, Route, Http in Angular?

Tags: angular

In which place of main `NgModule` should be register Angular's libraries:

```
ActivatedRoute, Route, Http in Angular
```

It is not services, not pipes or directives, therefore they can be registered in providers or imports:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [// HERE ],
  providers: [// OR HERE]

});
```

Is it right?

Comment: ActivatedRoute is used to access the route associated with the component. For example - Many times we send data through url like id and using Activatedroute we can access it. https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `imports` to import a module.
You use `providers` to specify your services to be available for dependency injection.

For example:

If you want to use the `ActivatedRoute` you will need to first `import` the `RouterModule`.

```
@NgModule({

  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}]),

  providers: []

});
```

Comment: I know, but what is that: ActivatedRoute, Route, Http in Angular?

Comment: `ActivatedRoute` is a way to access the current route (https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute).

Comment: I dont understand, why I can not use import Route directly in component without importing in `@NgModule`

Answer (score 1):

`ActivatedRoute` and `Route` are two embedded elements in `RouterModule` (which should be imported in **`imports`** part and there is no `Http` AFAIN (*unless you're talking about the protocol ;)* ), there is a `HttpModule` (***Deprecated, now it is replaced by `HttpClientModule`***)  which also should be imported next to the latter mentioned ones.

Comment: So, how to be, to import  `RouterModule` in AppModule or include `Route`, `ActivatedRoute` dirrectly in component?

Comment: @OPV If you'd imported RouterModule in AppModule (correcty , mean with a forRoot params), and in the same AppModule you declared a component, yes you can hence import `Route` or `ActivatedRoute` in this component and use them.

Comment: Why not enough to import Router ActivatedRoute in component without AppModule?

Comment: @OPV I didnt mention you should import them in AppModule, you should import their wrapper (RouterModule) in AppModule and that's all.

Comment: I did not get you, if I import to AppModule it is ok, but when I want to use instanca of Route in component, I import Route and use as: route: Route, this.route.call(). It means I import Route twice, one in RouterModule and second in component, is not?

Comment: Where to import Title if application uses this in whole components?

Comment: bah, not exactly, there is two different `imports`, one is a Typescript import the other is angular's one, Typescript import is those imports within the head of files (import .. from ..) , this type of importing wont overload your browser memory, it is like to make some exported data visible in somewhere else, that's all. Now for the angular Imports - those arrays in NgModule files - are there to build the  modules of your angular application (modules are a big basic part of angular).. Should make some researches tho